# How to install packages with conda into /usr/bin/python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, interpreter, sys.path

I have a package, that is only downloadable with `conda`. When I startup a shell and type `which python3`, I get `/home/usr/miniconda3/bin/python`. Then I do `conda deactivate` and my python3 is `/usr/bin/python3`. Is there any chance to install packages from conda, so that the python-interpreter in that location finds them?

Comment: Why do you want to do this, though? Wouldn’t it somewhat defeat the point of using Conda?

Comment: yes actually you are right. But I'm using a software calld Grass Gis and by what I know this software automatically uses `usr/binython3` as interpreter